# Implementation of scheme vector-set

Tags: vector, scheme, sicp

I am trying to understand how `vector-set!` is implemented. It looks to me like `vector-set!` is a special form - much like `set!` is. When I look at examples using `vector-set!` I see the following, desirable behavior (in guile).

```
(define test (lambda (v i) (vector-set! v i 0)))
(define v (make-vector 5 1))
v
$1 = #(1 1 1 1 1)
(test v 0)
v
$2 = #(0 1 1 1 1)
```

I can also do this (in guile)

```
(define test (lambda (v i) (vector-set! (eval v (interaction-environment)) i 0)))
(test (quote v) 3)
v
$21 = #(0 1 1 0 1)
```

Contrasting to the `set!` behavior:

```
(define a 1)
(define test2 (lambda b (begin (set! b 0) b)))
(test2 (quote a))
$26 = 0
a
$27 = 1
```

In this case, to my understanding the `set!` changes `b` to 0 (and not the 'evaluated" `b` (which should be `a`). The `eval` trick from above does not work here.

My question is: How is `vector-set!` implemented compared to `set!` (or [set-variable-value!](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_sec_4.1.1)). Does `vector-set!` peak at it's first argument? Or something else? I have tried to look at some of scheme implementations but extracting the gist from the code is tricky. Perhaps someone has an explanation or a link to some (sicp style) scheme implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `vector-set!` is a so-called *primitive*.
It is a function (not a special form), but it must be implemented within the runtime.

Note: A special form is a form that uses an evaluation order different from the order used in a normal application. Therefore `if`, `cond`, `or` and others are special forms.

Some implementations (I can't remember if Guile is one of them) has a function `primitive?` that can be used to test whether a function is a primitive or not.

```
> (primitive? vector-set!)
#t
```

Comment: Thanks. You would not know a reference I could look at - I am looking for something simple. My understanding not still clear about how `vector-set!` is implemented - should I be able to derive something from the fact that it is a primitive? Maybe there are other primitives besides `vector-set!` that show a similar behavior that I could look at?

Comment: Am I right in understanding that because `vector-set!` is not  a special form it's first argument (`v`) is evaluated and not auto quoted like that of `set!`?

Comment: Here is [Norvig's java implementation](http://norvig.com/jscheme/Primitive.java) that shows how the vector is an internal data structure that is modified by `vector-set!`

Answer (score 1):

In "some SICP-style Scheme implementation", where `vector-set!` would be handled by `eval-vector-mutation`, it could be

```
(define (eval-vector-mutation exp env)
    ; exp = (vector-set! vec idx val)
  (let ((vec (eval (vector-mutation-vec exp) env))
        (idx (eval (vector-mutation-idx exp) env))
        (val (eval (vector-mutation-val exp) env)))
    (begin
      (set-car! (cddr (drop vec idx)) val)  ; srfi-1 drop
      vec)))
```

and `make-vector` handled by

```
(define (eval-vector-creation exp env)
    ; exp = (make-vector cnt val)
  (let ((cnt (eval (vector-creation-cnt exp) env))
        (val (eval (vector-creation-val exp) env)))
    (cons 'vector                           ; tagged list
      (cons cnt                             ; vector size
        (make-list cnt val)))))             ; srfi-1 make-list
```

Here vectors are represented by tagged lists in the underlying Scheme implementation (not the Scheme being defined), and *its* mutation primitives, like `set-car!`, are used to manipulate them. If your implementation language were C, say, you'd just use C arrays as your vectors representation, or perhaps a structure coupling an array with the additional pertinent info, like its size ,etc.